# flash as3: anonymous objects creation when calling a function?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, object

If I want to send an object to a function with one child called foo equals "bar", i need to do the following:

```
var obj:Object = new Object();
obj.foo="bar";
myfunction(obj);
```

is there a way to declare the object in the function itself ? something like that:

```
myfunction(new Object{foo:"bar"});
```

thank you!

using flash-as3.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You almost had it in your example!

To create an object inline you use curly braces:

```
myfunction({foo:"bar"});
```

You can also do inline arrays with brackets:

```
myfunction(["bar", "baz"]);
```